# Libcamera-still got fixed blurry image problem after increasing cma , but Picamera2 still giving blurry image

Tags: picamera, libcamera

I'm using this raspberry pi zero 512mb ram. I've successfully connected the arducam 64mp camera and it's capturing 4kx3k resolution fine , after I changed the cma from 265m to 400m the libcamera-still command stopped giving blurry image and giving expected result. but when I'm capturing image using Picamera2 in python command , it's giving the same blurry image. what can i do ?